# How to convert an arbitary channel tensor to opencv dnn blob?

Tags: opencv, blob, tensor

I'm using opencv dnn for infering onnx model, and I'v found `dnn::blobFromImage` can transfer an image to blob as input of `dnn::Net`,  but if there anyway to transfer arbitary shape tensor (e.g. (1,8,256,256) instead of 3 channels) to blob for infering ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems no function specially.
Just construct this Mat:

```
    int arr[4] = {64, 8, 21, 3};
    Mat kp(4, arr, CV_32FC1, Scalar::all(0));
    cout << r.size() << endl;
    for (int b = 0; b < r.size(); b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < r[b].size(); c++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < r[b][c].size(); h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < r[b][c][h].size(); w++)
                {
                    kp.ptr<float>(b, c, h)[w] = r[b][c][h][w].asFloat();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```